# Multiple Row Headers Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, formatting, data-manipulation

G'day!

I'm trying to import some navigational data for use with flight planning.

Here is the format that the data comes in.

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpk96azr46ijngi/Screenshot%202014-01-22%2019.42.30.png
```

As you can see it has 2 rows for headers as the data spreads over a couple of rows for 1 airport.

Is there a way to import this CSV file straight into a mySQL database without further manipulation? Or will i have to manually change the data into a format that will fit.

If so, what way should i format it to be the most efficient?

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: If its not a pure programming requirement i would recommend using some ETL tool, e.g pentaho DI to migrate excel files to MYSQL DB. Other wise post your code where you are doing some thing